# Rails updating a table partial for a polymorphic object with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an issue with updating a table (adding/removing rows) when I create/destroy an object with ajax calls.

The application I'm working on can assign tasks to various categories, like projects, documents, etc. The task model is implemented with a polymorphic relationship to these objects.

I am currently rendering the task list and form to create a new task as partials. The form_for a new task uses ajax to show/hide the form and create a new task.

The issue that I'm having is that I'm able to create and destroy tasks and the form_for seems to be working. However, I cannot get the table to update when I try and re-render the partial in my js.erb calls. The table will only update on refresh.

(I'm also generating a 406 Unknown Format error on the destroy action which I haven't figured out yet, but since the destroy and create actions are the same I'm assuming I would still have the non-updating problem)

**tasks controller**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :my_tasks, :edit, :update, :destroy]  
    respond_to :html, :json, :js
.
.
.
  def create
    @assignable = find_assignable
    @task = @assignable.tasks.build(task_params)
    if @task.save
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html {redirect_to @task}
        end
    else
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
  end

  def new
    @assignable = params[:assignable_type].constantize.find_by(params[:assignable_id])
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def destroy
        @assignable = params[:assignable_type].constantize.find_by(params[:assignable_id])
        @assignable.tasks.find(params[:id]).destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html {redirect_to :action => :index, status: 303 }
        format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
.
.
.
def find_assignable
    params.each do |name, value|
        if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
            return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
        end
    end
       nil
end
```

The partial where I am creating the task list 
**tasks/_task_list**

```
    %tbody
      - assignable.tasks.each do |task|
        -# the path builder below only works if there is one underscore in the object name. MasterPo --> master_pos
        - path = "#{task.assignable_type.gsub(/([a-z])(?=[A-Z])/,'\1_\2').downcase.pluralize}/#{assignable.id}/tasks/#{task.id}" 
        %tr
          %td= best_in_place task, :description, :url => path
          %td= best_in_place task, :priority, :url => path
          %td= best_in_place task, :status, :as => :select, 
            :collection => {"1" => "Approved", "2" => "Pending", "3" => "Outstanding", "4" => "Review"}, :url => path
          %td= best_in_place task, :created_by, :url => path
          %td= task.assignable_type
          %td= link_to 'delete', 
            task_path(assignable, assignable_id: assignable.id, assignable_type: assignable.class.name, id: task.id), 
            remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure'} 

  %br

  .row
    .col-md-2.col-md-offset-4
      = link_to new_task_path(assignable, assignable_id: assignable.id, assignable_type: assignable.class.name), remote: true do
        %button.btn.btn-default New Task

  .row
    #task-form{:style => "display:none;"}

  :javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    /* Activating Best In Place */
    jQuery(".best_in_place").best_in_place();
  });
```

Which calls my form partial as given below for reference:

**tasks/_form**

```
= simple_form_for [@assignable, Task.new], remote: true do |f|
  - if Task.new.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this task from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  = f.input :description, as: :text
  = f.input :priority, collection: 1..5
  = f.input :status, collection: ["Open", "Completed", "Assigned"]
  = f.button :submit
```

Now, I'm assuming my error has to be in the way I am trying to render my _task_list partial in my create.js.erb and my destroy.js.erb. The js.erb files are given below:

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#tasks').html("<%= j (render partial: 'tasks/task_list', locals: {assignable: @assignable}) %>");
$('#task-form').slideUp(350);
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#task-form').html("<%= j (render 'form', locals: {assignable: @assignable}) %>");
$('#task-form').slideDown(350);
```

and **destroy.js.erb**

```
$('#tasks').html("<%= j (render partial: 'tasks/task_list', locals: {assignable: @assignable}) %>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was calling ajax on #tasks, without actually giving my form the div id='tasks' and so nothing was being updated. Unfortunately, I didn't include the top of the page so that was not obvious in my question

Answer (score 0):

Your @assignable object isn't reloaded.It still contains all the previous data. Define it again in the methods so that it will be updated and tha table will update in your view without refresh.

Comment: I tried defining @assignable.reload in the controller and in the create.js.erb files... when I debug it shows the new tasks before calling the create.js view, but still isn't updating the view. Where should I redefine it?